# Laplace of the PDE $ x \frac{\partial(w)}{\partial(x)} + \frac{\partial(w)}{\partial(t)}=xt$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Question is find the Laplace transform of this equation:
$$ x \frac{\partial(w)}{\partial(x)} + \frac{\partial(w)}{\partial(t)}=xt$$

Boundary conditions : $$ w(x,0) = 0 \qquad  x \geq0 $$
$$w(0,t)=0 \qquad t \geq 0$$

I've got as far as 
$$ \frac{d(W)}{d(x)}+\frac{s}{x}W=\frac{1}{s^2}$$

I'm not even sure this is correct but even if it is, I dont know how to integrate this to get $W(x,s)$

Comment: Try with $W = a x + b x^{-s}$ for some $a$ and $b$ which depend on $s$

Comment: The idea is that after you multiply by $x^s$, you get $x^s\frac{dW}{dx}+sx^{s-1}W$, which is $\frac{d(x^sW)}{dx}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dW}{dx}+\frac{s}{x}W=\frac{1}{s^2}$$

Following the hints in the comments, the solution of the equation is

$$W(x,s)=\dfrac{x}{s^2(s+1)}+c_1x^{-s}$$

But $W(0,s)=0$ and because it holds for any $s$

$$0=\dfrac{c_1}{x^s}\implies c_1=0$$

$$W(x,s)=\dfrac{x}{s^2(s+1)}$$

and

$$w(x,t)=x(e^{-t}+t-1)$$